# Какой знак препинания поставить?

Tags: пунктуация

Какой знак препинания вставить?

"...в котором собрали нас (?) учеников двенадцатого класса."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Приложение, которое  относится к личному местоимению, обособляется запятыми.

Тире же ставится тогда, когда приложению придаётся большое значение в высказывании,  оно часто находится в конце предложения (может быть и в середине) и носит ярко выраженный пояснительный характер. Чаще всего такое приложение относится не к местоимению, а к существительному.

В Вашем примере лучше поставить запятую.

Comment: А какой знак вы бы поставили в этом случая:  А вот и он убийца!

Comment: Вы же понимаете, что эта фраза особенная. Она понимается двояко, если поставить запятую после местоимения, и только  другие знаки или изменение структуры предложения должны внести ясность.

Answer (score 2):

Возможно как запятая, так и тире.

Дополнение. Ответ справочной службы русского языка Граммы.ру

В предложении "...в котором собрали нас - учеников двенадцатого класса" постановка тире возможна, так как приложение, относящееся к личному местоимению, имеет пояснительный характер. Пример такого употребления см.: Розенталь Д.Э. Справочник по пунктуации. М., 1984. С. 63.

Answer (score 0):

Лучше поставить запятую, так как это пояснение, а не присоединение: раскрывается значение местоимения.

Comment: Тире как раз подчеркивает пояснительный характер приложения. Ср.: По ночам часто плакал во сне Фунтик - маленькая рыжая такса (К.Паустовский).